# Are edits being misattributed to Community?

Tags: support, editing

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/51156/revisions for example. I don't think the automated Community user that bumps old posts edited in some more speculation about the date of the PDC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the "suggested" link above the user name, and you'll find [*the rest of the story*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/534): the edit was proposed by an anonymous user.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! One of those things that doesn't leap out...